# Css overflow and absolute on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a problem with CSS on Chrome.
I have a table with overflow and has a pop up button and the pop up has absolute position when clicked.
It is working as expected when running on Firefox :

[image: Firefox running]

But its run different on Chrome :
[image]

Is there anything I can do to fix the Chrome behaviour? To get the same behaviour as Firefox?

Additional :
I use bootstrap for the project. Here the table I made :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
```

And here the td of the button :

```
<td>
    <div class="btn-group dropdownn">
        <button id="dLabel" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" id="tombol_action">
            <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
            <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

And here the css i modified when the pop up opened:

```
<style>
.dropdownn.open{
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

Please check this, i have made the prototype http://jsfiddle.net/gjtcyL7y/3/

**Fixed :**
http://jsfiddle.net/gjtcyL7y/10/
Thanks to Ashish

Comment: Can you show as some code so we can understand better where the problem is?

Comment: Seeing your screen shot there might me lot many options for this behaviour so please give us or provideus some code to work on and give u the result

Comment: Please check, already added a code

Comment: I think this code is not enough. post some more code or create fiddle for your issue. your current code looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/1s1fgbx6/ .Whether you use any jquery plugins for popup?

Comment: I only use bootstrap here

Comment: Will you edit my fiddle and show issue which you get?

Comment: Please check this : i have made the proto for my problem http://jsfiddle.net/gjtcyL7y/3/

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work well on my Chrome. Perhaps the problem lies at other parts of the website?

Comment: Seems there is a problem on fiddle, the pop up should appear outside the scroll view. But I don't know why its appear inside the scroll view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.mydropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    var myBtn = $(this);
    
    
    
    var offset_t = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    var offset_l = $(this).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();
    
    console.log(offset_l, offset_t);
    myBtn.find(".dropdown-menu").css({"position":"fixed","left":offset_l,"top":offset_t + myBtn.height()});
   });
   $('.mydropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
    var myBtn = $(this);
    myBtn.find(".dropdown-menu").removeAttr("style");
   });
   
   
   $("#wrap").on("scroll", function(e) {
    var myBtn = $('.mydropdown.open');
    
    var offset_t = $(myBtn).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    var offset_l = $(myBtn).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();
    
    myBtn.find(".dropdown-menu").css({"position":"fixed","left":offset_l,"top":offset_t + myBtn.height()});
    
   });
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <div style="width:850px; overflow: scroll;height:450px;" id="wrap">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="example" ccellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Head1</th>
                <th>Head2</th>
                <th>Head3</th>
                <th>Head4</th>
                <th>Head5</th>
                <th>Head6</th>
                <th>Head7</th>
                <th>Head8</th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr>
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
   <tr height="48px">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Gabriel</td>
                    <td>Some value is here</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>Some value is here and little longer</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group mydropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pilih <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="View SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> View SPK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link/1" title="Edit SPK">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit SPK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

---

Comment: Hi Ashish, its almost fix. The bug comes when i have the row more than 1. Please check this : http://jsfiddle.net/gjtcyL7y/6/

Comment: It work now, by change the selector to '[id=mydropdown]'. Here the result : http://jsfiddle.net/gjtcyL7y/7/

Comment: @Apin An ID should be unique within a page, use use class instead of id. Please chk my updated Ans.

Comment: @Apin [id=mydropdown] and '#mydropdown' both are same selector both are working very well.

Comment: after checking it. It has another bug, when the we do the vertical scroll (not the table, but the Chrome vertical scroll). Please check this : http://jsfiddle.net/gjtcyL7y/9/. I have added more row so there is available vertical scroll. When you did the scroll and click the button, the pop up position is wrong.

Comment: @Apin please check my answer. i have updated. i think you want like this?

Comment: can you please tell me how to set it to correct? I don't know where is the button

Comment: @Apin do u want drop-down position set? don't worry about button Position

Comment: its OK already. What i am asking is how to mark my thread as fixed?